# OpenJDK vs. Oracle JDK for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, openjdk, jdk, oracle

When I run Android Studio with OpenJDK installed I get a warning recommending the use of Oracle JDK. Is Oracle JDK actually better or is it fine to just stick with OpenJDK? Installing Oracle JDK seems like a hassle compared to the simple `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` for OpenJDK. Are there any differences between the two I should be worried about?

Answer (score 5):

I think that it depends on what you are going to be doing. There are probably some compatibility issues for random features. I have not run into any myself, but you may be better off using the JDK from Oracle. [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) does a great job distributing the JDK via a PPA which makes it pretty easy to install on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

OpenJDK is more Open and thus also better to debug, fix and configure. It tends to be a bit slower though. Incompatibilities should not arise (anymore) - Android itself can be built using the OpenJDK.